# How can i extract time from datetime.datetime object in odoo

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
shift_from = datetime.strptime(shift_change_ob.shift_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
shift_to = datetime.strptime(shift_change_ob.shift_date_to, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
shift_time_from = self.get_zone_time(shift_from)
shift_time_to= self.get_zone_time(shift_to)
time_from  = datetime.strptime(str(shift_time_from),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").strftime("%H.%M")
time_to  = datetime.strptime(str(shift_time_to),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").strftime("%H.%M")
```

I want to get only time from `shift_time_from`  and `shift_time_to`. When I do this I get:

> ValueError: unconverted data remains: +00:00

How can I solve this?

Comment: every `datetime` object has method `time` for getting only time part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `shift_from` and `shift_to` are correct, then use the method `time` for getting only time part:

```
shift_time_from = shift_from.time()
shift_time_to = shift_to.time()
```